# How to assign ajax response to data element with vuejs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, vue.js

I am trying to consume json from a rails app and render a Vue application on the page. It seems, however, my data object never populates. The application is found by Vue. I figured I could make the assignment on success and the dom would update, but no. I tried it when done, but no. After the page completely renders, stuff.things only contains the observer object.

Here is the script:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var stuff = new Vue({
      el: '#stuff',
      data: {
        things: []
      },
      mounted: function() {
        // var that;
        // that = this;
        $.ajax({
          url: '/things.json',
          success: function(res) {

            this.things = res;
          }
        }).done(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            this.things.push(data);
        });
      }

    });
  </script>
```

Here is the div

```
<div id = "stuff">
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="thing in things">
        <td>hello</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</div>
```

Here is a part of the JSON from the page.

```
[{"id":1,"name":"this thingz","created_at":"2017-04-25T16:54:29.908Z","updated_at":"2017-04-25T17:00:32.519Z"},{"id":2,"name":"dsfsdfd","created_at":"2017-04-25T17:00:56.880Z","updated_at":"2017-04-25T17:00:56.880Z"},{"id":3,"name":"sadsa","created_at":"2017-04-25T17:07:20.084Z","updated_at":"2017-04-25T17:07:20.084Z"},{"id":4,"name":"","created_at":"2017-04-25T17:09:00.686Z","updated_at":"2017-04-25T17:09:00.686Z"},{"id":5,"name":"","created_at":"2017-04-25T17:11:42.989Z","updated_at":"2017-04-25T17:11:42.989Z"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lost your context when you defined your ajax callback.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/things.json',
  success: function(res) {
    this.things = res;
  }.bind(this)
})
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/qmqmKG?editors=1010).

You could also do it with some of the code you commented out.

```
mounted: function() {
  const that = this
  $.ajax({
    url: '/things.json',
    success: function(res) {
      that.things = res;
    }
  });
}
```